# Data Grid View not showing data from related models?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two related classes:

```
public class Dealer {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<DealerAddress> DealerAddress { get; set; }
}

public class DealerAddress { 
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int DealerId { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public virtual Dealer Dealer { get; set; }
}
```

And in my form I want to display data from DealerAddress class:

```
 public SortableBindingList<DealerAddress> Addresses = new SortableBindingList<DealerAddress>();   


 private void CreateDataGridView() {
    dataGridViewPlaceHolderPanel.Visible = false;
    dataGridView = new DataGridView();
    dataGridView.Name = "dataGridView";

    List<string> regularColumns = new List<string>()
    {
        nameof(DealerAddress.Id),
        nameof(DealerAddress.DealerId),
        nameof(DealerAddress.Dealer.BaseUrl),
        nameof(DealerAddress.Email),
    };

    var columns = new List<DataGridViewTextBoxColumn>();

    foreach (var regularColumnName in regularColumns)
    {
        var col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        {
            HeaderText = regularColumnName,
            DataPropertyName = regularColumnName,
            Name = "column" + regularColumnName
        };
        columns.Add(col);
    }
}

  public void SetAddresses(SortableBindingList<DealerAddress> addresses, int totalCount)
    {
        try
        {
            dataGridView.RowStateChanged -= DataGridView_RowStateChanged;
            Addresses = addresses;
            RefreshDataGridView();
        }
        finally
        {
            dataGridView.RowStateChanged += DataGridView_RowStateChanged;
        }
    }


    private void RefreshDataGridView(){
        if (Addresses == null || Addresses.Count == 0)
            return;

        dataGridView.DataSource = Addresses;
    }
```

And the data displayed in my table is:

[image]

When I hit "SetAddresses", the data is populated from DealerAddress model, but it doesn't display column values from "DealerAddress.Dealer".

Comment: can you paste definetion of `Addresses`, and note this should be a property?

Comment: Please check the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Quick fix it with the following. In your `DealerAddres`, add

```
    public string BaseUrl
    {
        get => Dealer.BaseUrl;

        set => Dealer.BaseUrl = value;
    }
```

---

**Explaining**

You have two class `DealerAddress` and `Dealer`. You `set` a list of `DealerAddress` to the `DataSource`.

So when the `DataGridView` starts to render, it will search the `properties` in the first class.

When you do `nameof(DealerAddress.Dealer.BaseUrl)` you are actually telling, to the `DataGridView`, that the class `DealerAddress` contains that property --- which it does not.

---

[See this for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2382177/5734097).